# issue with xmlhttprequest, not sure is is call correct?

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have this code where a user chooses a sales center and then it will change the currency
both of them are dropdowns,the issue im having is when i choose a sales center i get a error
ReferenceError: makeRequest is not defined. im not sure if im calling it right or what is going on.   im not sure if i did the xmlhttprequest part correct(first time doing it)

```
HTP.P('<td class="reqlabel1">Sales Center:</td>');
HTP.P('<td class="tablelabel">');
HTP.P(Get_Sc_Dd(PVNAME=>'pnSalesCenterID', PVORAID=> VUSERNAME, PVDEFVAL => NSALESCENTERID, PVEVENT=>'class="reqinput1" onChange="makeRequest();" style="width:260px"'));
HTP.P('</td>

');
```

---

```
CURRDEF := get_criteria_rec('PROCURR_DEF',dml_p_oracle_user.get_rec(VUSERNAME).global_region).include_list;


HTP.P( '...>
function makeRequest(){
ajaxReq = (window.XMLHttpRequest)? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

ajaxReq.open("POST","contr_entry_pkg.sales_center_dropdown?&pnSalesCenterID="document.getElementById("pnSalesCenterID")+ "&pvCurrCd="document.getElementById("'||CURRDEF||'"),true);
ajaxReq.onreadystatechange =function()currencychange;

ajaxReq.send()
}
function currencychange(){

if(ajaxReq.readyState == 4){
if(ajaxReq.status == 200){
//var resultsJSON = eval(''('' + ajaxReq.responseText + '')'');
document.getElementById("pvCurrCd").innerHTML = ajaxReq.responseText;

}

}
}');
   HTP.P( '</script>');
                    HTP.P('<td class="reqlabel1">Currency:</td>');
        HTP.P('<td class="tablelabel">');

         HTP.P(Get_currencyCode_Dd(PVNAME=>'pvCurrCd', 
         PVDEFVAL =>NULL,    
           PVEVENT=>'class="reqinput1"onBlur="makeRequest() style="width:200px"'));
       HTP.P('</td>');
```

Comment: What variant of Javascript is this?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse` rather than `eval` to parse JSON.

Comment: You're missing a doublequote after `onBlur="makeRequest()`

Comment: barmar , eval is actually commented out, not sure what you mean

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. Putting everything in strings disables the syntax coloring that would distinguish comments from code.

Comment: What is all that `HTP.P(...)` stuff? Is it some Javascript framework or template language?

Comment: and the doublequote is not what is wrong

Comment: is just to make the javascript and plsql stuff we have work together, i know for sure that is not what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct Javascript syntax:

```
ajaxReq.onreadystatechange =function()currencychange;
```

it should be:

```
ajaxReq.onreadystatechange = currencychange;
```

Comment: thanks , but i have try it both ways and nothing, still get same error

Comment: There are usually two reasons for that error: 1) A syntax error prevented the function from being defined (that's what I thought the above was doing), or 2) the function is defined in the inner scope of another function, so you can't reference it from inline JS in the HTML (they can only access global variables). There seem to be a couple of extra close braces after the `currencychange` function, does that mean they're inside another function?

Comment: Never mind that last comment, the lack of indentation confused me. Those braces are for the `if` statements in `currencychange`. It's really hard to help with questions that are so horribly formatted.

Comment: i think you may be right with (2) and no they are not inside another function,i also thought it maybe the way i use XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Nothing about the way you use XMLHttpRequest would affect whether the function is defined.

Comment: pnSalesCenterID and pvcurrcd are global